# Code sample to remove all special characters from data stored in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, filter, character

Does anyone have a code sample where I can to remove all special characters from data stored in MYSQL?

I need to remove the following special characters:

> : ~!@#$%*()_+{}[];':"<>?

Comment: a code sample in what language? PHP? ASP? PERL?

Comment: example as : SELECT * FROM Film where removeSpecial(Film.name) = search.

Comment: If you're working with ascii text, maybe it would be simpler to specify the characters you want to allow rather than the ones you want to strip out.

Comment: Search name in my table is many character speacial .

Answer (score 3):

Try this... It looks terrible, but it works

```
SELECT * FROM Film where REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Film.name,':',''),'~',''),'!',''),'@',''),'#',''),'$',''),'%',''),'*',''),'(',''),')',''),'_',''),'+',''),'{',''),'}',''),'[',''),']',''),';',''),'''',''),':',''),'"',''),'<',''),'>',''),'?','') = ?
```

This one will also strip out space:

```
SELECT * FROM Film where REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Film.name,':',''),'~',''),'!',''),'@',''),'#',''),'$',''),'%',''),'*',''),'(',''),')',''),'_',''),'+',''),'{',''),'}',''),'[',''),']',''),';',''),'''',''),':',''),'"',''),'<',''),'>',''),'?',''),' ','') = ?
```

Comment: That is because it has to do the replace for every single row. Is it possible to add a special column `name_search` for the one without special characters? You could keep it up to date every night like this `UPDATE Film SET name_search = REPLACE....(name, ....)` Then you could run the search on name_search and the replacing will already be done. It would also allow you to use the LIKE operator and make better uses of indexes which would make things faster

Comment: Thanks for showing us, that MySQL should never be used in everything that exceeds university-homeworks!

Comment: @KenyakornKetsombut, Really?